# How to automatically truncate the length of a line in vim-latex?

Tags: vim

Is there a way of automatically beginning a new line after reaching a particular length of a line in order to make navigation through a document easier in vim-latex?

Example (text from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giraffe):

Instead of having this:

```
\documentclass[letter,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{sidecap}

\begin{document}
\begin{SCfigure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.55\textwidth]{Giraffa_camelopardalis_angolensis}
\caption{The giraffe (\emph{Giraffa camelopardalis}) is an African even-toed ungulate mammal, the tallest of all land-living animal species. Males can be 4.8 to 5.5~metres tall and weigh up to 1,360~kilograms. The record-sized bull was 5.87~m tall and weighed approximately 2,000~kg. Females are generally slightly shorter and weigh less than the males do.}
\end{SCfigure}
\end{document}
```

Getting this while typing:

```
\documentclass[letter,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{sidecap}

\begin{document}
\begin{SCfigure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.55\textwidth]{Giraffa_camelopardalis_angolensis}
\caption{The giraffe (\emph{Giraffa camelopardalis}) is an African even-toed
ungulate mammal, the tallest of all land-living animal species. Males can be
4.8 to 5.5~metres tall and weigh up to 1,360~kilograms. The record-sized bull
was 5.87~m tall and weighed approximately 2,000~kg. Females are generally
slightly shorter and weigh less than the males do.}
\end{SCfigure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Go to the specific line and press `gqap`. If you want to reformat the complete text, just select it in visual mode (`ggVG<ESC>`) and then do a `gqap`

Comment: This is actually a Vim question and belongs more on http://stackoverflow.com or http://superusers.com. Try to `set textwidth=80` and ensure that `formatoptions` includes at least `t`. You best do this in the user config file (`~/.vimrc` under Linux). Existing lines can be broken my marking them and pressing `<ESC>gw`.

Comment: And *please* stop forcing the output driver (`pdftex`) on `graphicx` and other packages. This is no longer required and should be avoided.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want long lines to be wrapped while typing, use:

```
:set textwidth=72
```

or any other value.

In the `.vimrc` file:

```
autocmd FileType tex    set textwidth=72
```

Comment: I'd vote for writing `set textwidth=79` to `~/.vim/ftplugin/tex.vim`, saves you the `autocmd FileType tex` part and is more extensible if you like to add more tex specific options at a later point.